# Open search for string in page via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to emulate Ctrl+F and open a seach that is build in web brouser. Like user press a button and onlick effect shown build in search.
I do not what to build my search or use some public search. I am curious, is it possible to open web brouser search?

This do not work = window.find('string');

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Open a Google Drive Document for example, and hit Ctrl+F. You will see that Google captures the keystrokes and presents you with a custom Find box.

Also, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091640/290343).