# Do browser shortcut keys depend on locale?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, browser

**In short :** Do browser shortcut keys depend on locale ?

**More precisely :**

The initial idea was to state whether disabling browser find by preventing default behavior for `Ctrl+F` in javascript do ALWAYS prevent browser search (putting aside browser search can be triggered by other means).

Reading this stackoverflow post, and @Joachim Sauer's comment [Is it possible to disable Ctrl + F of find in page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091538/is-it-possible-to-disable-ctrl-f-of-find-in-page#comment-8489798), I tried to determine whether this was true :

> Note that [...] it will not prevent the user [...] from using an alternative shortcut if he's using a locale that uses some other key-combination for searching.

Based on this [FireFox documentation](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/keyboard-shortcuts-perform-firefox-tasks-quickly), it seems that Find is always Ctrl+F, even if locale is different.

I also found this [chromium issue 5100](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5100), where someone complains that Windows has shortcuts that depends on local (Search is `Ctrl+L` in Portuguese for `Localizar`), whereas for chromium used in Portuguese local under Windows it is not the case (always `Ctrl+F`)

- Do you confirm that in main browsers, shortcut keys do not depend on locale ?
- Do you have any official documentation about it ?

Comment: If you want to prevent user to do some search on your page, you're wasting your time, not possible. You can open "Find" by pressing `F3`, it's found from "Edit" menu, you can search with Dev tools...

Comment: I know about that point, which is solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091538/is-it-possible-to-disable-ctrl-f-of-find-in-page post. But my question is about shortcut key being locale dependent. I will update the post so it is clearer.