# CTRL+F moves overflow:hidden <div>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a slider but discovered that if a user were to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, the position and the `<div>` element's offset changed and so the slider no longer works the way is should.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width:100px; height:150px;">
    <div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
        <div id="slider" style="width:200px; height:100px; right:0; position:relative;">
            <div style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;">visible</div>
            <div style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;">hidden</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="sliderbuttonprev" type="button" style="float:left;" value="Prev">
    <input id="sliderbuttonnext" type="button" style="float:right;" value="Next">
</div>
```

**JavaScript** (jQuery):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#sliderbuttonnext").click(function(){
        $("#slider").animate({right:"+=100px"});
    });
    $("#sliderbuttonprev").click(function(){
        $("#slider").animate({right:"-=100px"});
    });
});
```

Is there a way to stop <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+ <kbd>F</kbd> finding the hidden sections?

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/TaZL2/1/)

Comment: WHAT!? I've made 1000's of sliders and never had a problem with the find shortcut. Can you [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/) your issue?

Comment: He's right: http://jsfiddle.net/TaZL2/1/

Comment: OIC, interesting. Because you're sliding panels of text.

Comment: Wow this is quite an interesting problem... I'm not sure I'd choose the solution of removing the ability to find a piece of text the user is searching for.

Comment: seems to work on chrome or i missing something

Comment: @A.Wolff - try typing something into the search. (the opposite of what is visible)

Comment: You can cancel the CTRL + F key combination and create your own search box. Where you say it shouldn't search in your slider. Note that F3 is also a key that activates the searchbox.

Comment: This [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TaZL2/3/) kind of works, probably just need to give it some more effort

Comment: Check [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/TaZL2/4/) out too. The `<div>'s` with `float:left` are getting pushed to the next line so that just needs to be figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i came up with a solution that uses a variable to track the position of the main wrapping div and hides ".hide()" the content div that's not visible. hidden content is not visible to ctrl f.

**HTML:**

```
<div style="width:100px; height:150px;">
<div style="width:100px; height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
    <div id="slider" style="width:200px; height:100px; right:0; position:relative;">
        <div style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;">
            <div id="id1">visible</div>
        </div>
        <div style="width:100px; height:100px; float:left;">
            <div id="id2">hidden</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input id="sliderbuttonprev" type="button" style="float:left;" value="Prev">
<input id="sliderbuttonnext" type="button" style="float:right;" value="Next">
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
var pos = 0;
function showfunct(x){
   if(x==0)$("#id1").show();
   if(x==100)$("#id2").show();
}

function hidefunct(x){
   if(!(x==0))$("#id1").hide();
   if(!(x==100))$("#id2").hide();
}
showfunct(pos);
hidefunct(pos);
$(document).ready(function() { 

$("#sliderbuttonnext").click(function(){
    pos+=100;
    showfunct(pos);
    $("#slider").animate({right:"+=100px"});
    $("#slider").promise().done(function(){
        hidefunct(pos);
    });
});
$("#sliderbuttonprev").click(function(){
    pos-=100;
    showfunct(pos);
    $("#slider").animate({right:"-=100px"});
    $("#slider").promise().done(function(){
        hidefunct(pos);
    });
});
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent browsers from finding hidden content, but you could potentially disable it for the slides.

For example, if you specify the content within CSS, the browser won't move the content. For example, see here > [Is it possible to disable Ctrl + F of find in page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091538/is-it-possible-to-disable-ctrl-f-of-find-in-page)

```
<div class="word-foobar"></div>

.word-foobar:before {
    content: "Foobar";
}
```

As nickf has suggested, you could easily write some JavaScript code to convert actual text to this method.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/TaZL2/2/

If you change your animation to `marginLeft` instead of the `right` property, the content doesn't seem to scroll when searching. (Chrome/Mac OSX)

However, a user would still see there was a match and be stumped as to where it could be.

```
 $("#sliderbuttonnext").click(function () {
     $("#slider").animate({
         marginLeft: "-=100px"
     });
 });
 $("#sliderbuttonprev").click(function () {
     $("#slider").animate({
         marginLeft: "+=100px"
     });
 });
```

Comment: gives me same weird behaviour (chrome win7)

Comment: @A.Wolff - damn. Got any other browsers to try it on? FF/Mac OSX is working for me.

Comment: FF doesn't seems to get this issue

Comment: 3 out of 4 ain't bad. Pity quite a few users would be Chrome/Win7 combo.