# Is there a way to capture the ctrl-f focus event?

Tags: javascript, html, events

A user of my site <CTRL-F>s (using the usual browser built-in <CTRL-F> functionality) and searches for "pickles".  The term "pickles" is found 27 times, and they proceed to <CTRL-G> (or use the equivalent arrow buttons) to cycle through the matches on the page.

Are there any page events that fire on anything at any point in this process?  Like, for example, does a `focus` event happen on the selected match when they ?

My specific use case is that I would like to expand collapsed content that contains a search term when I search_for/focus_on that term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to disable Ctrl + F of find in page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091538/is-it-possible-to-disable-ctrl-f-of-find-in-page)

Comment: @msanford no.  I do *not* want to disable ctrl-f.  Detecting that someone has typed ctrl-f does not really help me assist them in their search.  Although, I did ask for ways to get events at any point in the search process, so I suppose this is one small part of an answer.

Comment: The OP of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26538831/can-a-browser-search-collapsed-content) actually has a similar use-case to mine.  However, 1) they didn't really get an answer that solves the problem and 2) Other questions seem to have implied that there are, in fact, *NO* events that fire during the ctrl-f search process, excepting the keyboard events.  I wanted to ask a question about the entire process to either confirm this, or to indentify other potential entry-points for participating in user page-search.