# In Firefox, how do I prevent Ctrl+F in an element while keeping the element visible to the user?

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, textarea, syntax-highlighting

[My open-source library](https://github.com/WebCoder49/code-input/) duplicates content as part of its aim to become a [textarea](/questions/tagged/textarea) element for syntax-highlighted code. The user **enters code into a `<textarea>` element, then the code is copied into a `<pre><code>` element** displayed behind the `<textarea>` and highlighted with Prism.js/highlight.js.

**[An issue with this](https://github.com/WebCoder49/code-input/issues/65) is that using Ctrl+F on the page returns duplicate results, a result for each occurrence in the `<textarea>` and another result for the same occurence in the `<pre><code>` element.**

I have **already implemented [this fix](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7091721/21785620) using the CSS `content` property on the `::before` pseudo-element** which works perfectly on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge, but it **makes no difference in *Mozilla Firefox* (Firefox includes the CSS content attribute in Ctrl+F).**

Can anyone suggest a Firefox-compatible fix? My library is an HTML custom element that must be as **self-contained** and **customisable** as possible, and I **don't want to make my own Ctrl+F search bar** unless I really need to because the library must emulate a vanilla `<textarea>` as much as possible.

My JavaScript function has access to the code as text, the `<textarea>` element, and the `<pre>` and `<pre><code>` elements and can modify them before or after code is highlighted with each keystroke.